# Undo send email in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

Is there an equivalent of [Undo Sent](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/03/new-in-labs-undo-send.html) Gmail feature in Microsoft Outlook?
I believe that once that feature is enabled in Gmail the sending of email is postponed by 5 to 30 seconds (depending on settings) so you have a chance to click on undo link.

Is there a similar feature available for Microsoft Outlook?

I am aware of [Recall Email](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/recall-or-replace-a-message-after-it-is-sent-HA001230419.aspx) functionality but that is a completely different approach requiring that the recipient of the mail must be using an Exchange server e-mail.

Comment: What version of Outlook are you running?  Are you using an Exchange server?

Comment: Sounds like someone shouldn't be making fun of their boss in emails!!! :)

Comment: @N_Lindz it is 2007, and I am using the exchange server.

Comment: @Jeff that is just a prevention measure ;)

Comment: I have the same question. You can make a rule to delay the sending of an email but you CANT undo the sending of the email. It is still going to be sent....just delayed by a minute. This is not the equivalent "undo send" in Gmail. Am I correct on this? update: I just saw this
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/use-outlook-rules-to-prevent-oh-no-after-sending-emails/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can delay delivery of your emails by setting up a rule in Outlook just like in Gmail. In this way, you'll have a chance to stop the delivery. Read the following How-To Geek article:

[Use Outlook Rules to Prevent "Oh No!" After Sending Emails](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/use-outlook-rules-to-prevent-oh-no-after-sending-emails/)

[image]

Comment: thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for, I tested on Outlook 2007 and works as expected

Comment: Is there a similar way to do this in Office 2011? I don't see the same options.

Comment: There should be. Can't you see the rules menu?

Comment: Not available for mac.

Comment: The answer should include information from the link in case the page becomes unavailable. Link only answers are generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 2):

As [Mehper C. Palavuzlar](https://superuser.com/a/235268/358766) pointed out, you can delay email delivery in Outlook by creating a rule. The method of doing this will be *slightly* different depending on your version of Outlook.

---

### Outlook 2016/2013/2010

1. Go to to **File -> Manage Rules & Alerts**.

[image: Rules & Alerts button]

2. Click **New Rule**.

[image: New Rule button]

3. Under **Start from a Blank Rule**, select **Apply rule on messages I send**, then click **Next**.

[image: Apply rule on message I send]

4. Do not select any special conditions, (*i.e. leave the checkboxes blank*), and click **Next**.

[image: No conditions selected]

5. If no options were selected, confirm that **Yes**, the rule should be applied to all sent messages.

[image: Apply rule to all sent messages]

6. In the list of actions, select **defer delivery by a number of minutes**.

[image: Defer delivery checkbox]

7. In the **Step 2: Edit the rule description** box, click the underlined phrase **a number of** to set the delay length, select **OK**, then click **Next**.

[image: Deferred delivery amount in minutes]

8. Follow the prompts to add any exceptions, then click **Next**.
9. Type a name under **Specify a name for this rule**, select the **Turn on this rule** checkbox, then click **Finish**.

[image: Finish creating rule]

---

### Outlook 2007/2003

1. On the **Tools** menu, click **Rules and Alerts**.

[image: Word 2007 - Tools -> Rules and Alerts]

2. Click **New Rule**.

[image: New Rule button]

2. Under **Start from a Blank Rule**, select **Check messages after sending**, then click **Next**.

[image: Check messages after sending]

3. Do not select any special conditions, (*i.e. leave the checkboxes blank*), and click **Next**.

[image: No conditions selected]

4. If no options were selected, confirm that **Yes**, the rule should be applied to all sent messages.

[image: Apply rule to all sent messages]

5. In the list of actions, select **defer delivery by a number of minutes**.

[image: Defer delivery checkbox]

6. In the **Step 2: Edit the rule description** box, click the underlined phrase **a number of** to set the delay length, select **OK**, then click **Next**.

[image: Deferred delivery amount in minutes]

7. Follow the prompts to add any exceptions, then click **Next**.
8. Type a name under **Specify a name for this rule**, select the **Turn on this rule** checkbox, then click **Finish**.

[image: Finish creating rule]

#### Sources

- [How-To Geek: Use Outlook Rules to Prevent "Oh No!" After Sending Emails](http://Use%20Outlook%20Rules%20to%20Prevent%20%22Oh%20No!%22%20After%20Sending%20Emails)
- [Microsoft Support: Delay or schedule sending email messages](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Delay-or-schedule-sending-email-messages-026af69f-c287-490a-a72f-6c65793744ba)
- [PC Magazine: How to Undo Send in Outlook](http://www.pcmag.com/commentary/350259/how-to-undo-send-in-outlook)

Answer (score -1):

*There is really no way to undo the sending of an email in Outlook.*

If you think of it soon enough, unplug your ethernet cable or stop the `Send & Receive` command from completing...

Comment: or hit that reset button ..

Comment: Don't PC's come with the reboot/reset button nowadays ? Yeah, I meant the abrupt shutdown route.. not really a great solution, hence the comment :) @studiohack

Comment: yeah, you had me confused for a moment, @Sathya, because I was thinking that you meant a reset button for Outlook, so I was like where?! :P

Comment: hehe, sorry 'about that @studiohack